# Mindmeister API object not found

Tags: rest, mindmapping

I am trying to insert a new idea into my mindmap. Here is my request.

```
curl --location '<https://www.mindmeister.com/services/rest/oauth2?map_id=2925023339&method=mm.ideas.insert&parent_id=2926361857&title=test>   
--header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_KEY
```

I get a following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsp stat="fail">
    <err code="20" msg="Object not found"/>
</rsp>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this? I am getting crazy.

Answer (score 0):

According to their support team, this is not possible.
https://community.meister.co/discussion/2000/mindmeister-api-object-not-found#latest
[image: screen shot of their reply]